# Alternatives to inline event like onclick , onchange etc

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, parameters, onclick

I have application where I use in line events like on click , on change , in JavaScript.I am revamping the application .moving everything to J-QUERY. Here I do not want to use any JavaScript in html file as  am using for AJAX request.want to keep it clean.So I searching for the alternatives for in line events.I have lots of links in the page and sending lots of parameters as a AJAX request. need a solution.

Comment: have you tried googling???

Comment: yes, didnt find any best solution.

Comment: Are these links helpful? .. https://api.jquery.com/click/
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: impossible not use javascript for event handling.

Comment: Here i an using lots of links and each has some parameters associated with them which is needed to be passed as a ajax request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inline events does not belong in the HTML structure. Lets keep separation of code. We will do this separation by either of two approaches

1. With jQuery Only - Bind the events on the HTML elements at the document load. Typical Example :

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
           <script>
               $(document).ready(function() {        
                   // All Hyperlinks 
                   $("a").on("click", function() {
                       // Do Something here 
                   });
               });
           </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           ..your html elements
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. (Recommended but requires quick learning curve ) Use any of the frameworks - AngularJS Or BackboneJs - which completely separate Model and Views. The "HTML" is rendered by the view and View is responsible for the Events binding on the HTML elements. Your HTML will be plain HTML and no JS will be present there.

Comment: here the problem is there lots of links . and i am passing parameters which i cant hardcode into js. they have dynamic values which i get when page loads. based on those parameters functions in server execute. if i keep specifying the ID as selector it would be big file.that much links are there.

Comment: @vishnuk_22 - You should give example of the links - Further all the hyperlinks can be selected by one jQuery Statement - $('a').on('click',function(){});

Comment: well in a page each link(could be anchor or button) has some unique parameters associated with it .when we click on a particular link it sends a ajax request with those parameters.based on those parameters its's decided where to go and execute. now problem is i cant add separate function for each link. i need a method to handle all link without writing on click function for each link. OR is there any way i could hold those parameters in html document and when event fires parameters belong to the particular link send to be handled in ajax